# Resolving (repeatedly) auto-bumped questions that have new answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, community-user, bump

Something I've noticed about some of the community-user bumped questions, most recently and specifically this one:
[What does "scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818657/what-does-scope-parameter-that-is-not-valid-for-an-aggregate-function-mean)

Honestly, it looks like a less than stellar question.  On the other hand, it does have error text in the body and could apply to others, so some searches will direct users there.

The [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15818657/timeline) shows that it has been "bumped by community user" five times.

[image]

I added an answer in part so that the question wouldn't see a sixth bump.  After all, the community bump is there for a reason, presumably in order to direct attention and provide some impetus to bringing questions towards resolution.

As things are going, I think the question is headed towards bump #6.  If that's due to the quality of the answer, or even specific to this question, that would be fine.  However, it looks like part of a trend:

- Many of the bumped questions are unlikely to be accepted by a long-gone OP.
- Some questions tend towards less than clear answers, but others just aren't attention-getters.
- This is compounded for questions in low-traffic tags.

Those seem like factors that can prevent this whole bump routine from making progress towards its escape cases.  In some cases, a single downvote on the question would be enough to take it out of rotation if appropriate.

I gave a shot at hacking together a user query for those bumped questions who have a new answer posted in the last X days but still are not resolved:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/544775/bumped-posts-new-answer-yet-unresolved?DaysPrevious=60

*Is there something that can be done about some of these?*  There are likely more than a couple of questions that could use attention and up/down-voting on their own merits.  And if the question is really that unlikely to attract any positively rated answers **and** the issue is quality-related, I would imagine that would warrant attention as well.

Comment: Keep in mind that getting a good answer is just one resolution.  If the question really is bad, it getting closed, and/or downvoted would be the appropriate resolution.

Comment: What is the "bump" we're talking about here?  I don't understand.

Comment: @Servy Absolutely; there are more than a couple of questions in the mix that should be old yeller'd.

Comment: @nhgrif Periodically questions with no answers and a zero score will be marked as having "activity" (attributed to the community user) even when there hasn't been any activity on the question, moving it to the top of the quesiton list when sorting by activity.

Comment: So all @bitnine or anyone concerned about these bumps has to do is post an answer and vote on the question?  I mean, this 6 month old question has no votes at all.

Comment: @nhgrif Not quite.  The criteria are a question with a non-negative score and no accepted or positively scored answers.  In my example, I added an answer.  However, a new 0-scored answer doesn't actually move that question out of the bump zone and upvoting the *question* has no impact.  Downvoting the question or upvoting any *answer* would do so, with the caveat that shouldn't just be done for its own sake.

Comment: @Servy actually, [positive scored questions with no upvoted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/155074)

Comment: The question you gave as an example received a recent answer. It was a decent answer and so I upvoted it. The problem has now been solved, assuming the answer score does not get back to 0 it will never be bumped again. I would say in the future just handle them like any other question; they will naturally meet their appropriate fate over time.

Comment: I'm not sure I even understand what the problem is...

Comment: @4386427 I suggest you read it once more then.